# Loop in taxonomy for terms and post

Tags: loop, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm having trouble getting this to work.  I've created a custom taxonomy named article_subjects and am looping thru, displaying each term; but am trying to get the newest post for each term

```
    <section>
    <?php
        $args = array (
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'number' =>      '4'
        );

        $terms = get_terms( 'article_subjects', $args );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <div>

            <?php 
                $postargs = array (
                    'tax_query' => array (
                        array (
                            'taxonomy' => 'article_subjects',
                            'field'    => 'name',
                            'terms'    => $term->slug,
                            'number'    => '1'
                        )
                    )
                );
                global $wp_query;
                $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?>
                    <p class="date"><?php echo $post->the_date ?></p>
                    <h3><?php echo $post->the_title ?></h3>
                    <p class="description"><?php echo $post->the_excerpt ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        <?php }
    ?>
</section>
```

Comment: what's not working with your code presently? note that `number` isn't a valid argument in `tax_query`, I assume you want to set [`posts_per_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: No need to call the global `wp_query`

Comment: You should definitely consult the Codex on [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of **guessing** how it works. By the way: `$post->the_date`, `$post->the_title` and `$post->the_excerpt` are not valid properties.

Comment: No guessing, just having trouble with it.  Got it working now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong:

1. In your code you are using the same $args array in the WP_Query call that you used in your get_terms call.  Perhaps you meant to use $postargs in the WP_Query call?
2. @Milo is correct...you should be using posts_per_page, not number.
3. Your tax_query array element 'field' says 'name' but you pass it the term slug and not the term name.

Hopefully this helps:  [Here is the reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Getting things mixed up before, got it working now.  Thanks.  This is the code I finally ended up with for my purposes:

```
<section id="top-columns">
    <?php $args = array (
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'number' =>      '4'
    );

    $terms = get_terms( 'article_subjects', $args );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $post_args = array (
            'post_type'  => 'post',
            'article_subjects' => $term->name,
            'posts_per_pge'    => '1'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $post_args );

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
            $query->the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <?php 
                    the_date();
                    the_title();
                    the_excerpt();
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php }

        wp_reset_postdata();
       } ?>
</section>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  I'm sure you caught it but there's a typo in 'posts_per_pge (page)'